# as3 ExternalInterface.call causing browser crash

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3

I've written an html page that is using some javascript to hide and display a flash movie object. It all works fine until I try to exit from the tab, and when that happens the entire browser will crash with not so much as an error text box. Can anyone help? Thanks

Flash Code

```
if(ExternalInterface.available)
ExternalInterface.call('hideTimeline');
```

Javascript code

```
function showTimelineFirstPlay()
{
var timeline = document.createElement('span');
timeline.id = "timeLineer"
//  WIDTH=1217 HEIGHT=170

//document.write(document.getElementById('topper').offsetHeight);
var fHeight = document.getElementById('topper').offsetHeight;
var fWidth = document.getElementById('topper').offsetWidth - 10;
var hHeight = fHeight + 100;
var hWidth = fWidth - 150;

timeline.innerHTML = "<OBJECT id='fTrans' allowScriptAccess='sameDomain' style = 'solid;border-color:#960000; border-width:3px;position:absolute; top:95; left:15;' classid='clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000' codebase='http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=9,0,0,0' WIDTH="+fWidth+" HEIGHT="+fHeight+"> <PARAM NAME=movie VALUE='FirstPlay.swf'> <PARAM NAME=quality VALUE=high> <PARAM NAME=bgcolor VALUE=#ffffff> </object><span onclick='hideTimeline()'style='color:#0098db;position:absolute; left:"+hWidth+"; top:"+hHeight+"'>- Hide Timeline</sapn>";

topper.appendChild(timeline);
}

function hideTimeline()
{
topper.removeChild(document.getElementById('timeLineer'));
}

window.onload = function()
{
showTimelineFirstPlay();
}
```

Comment: Did you try to reboot? Scripts should never crash a browser. If it is faulty code post what the issue is/was

Comment: That's just it I'm not sure exactly what the issue is. I know that when the actionscript is calling the Javascript method using the ExternalInterface.call it causes some error. When you attempt to close the tab after that call has been made it crashes the browser but gives no error messages.

Comment: The plug in might be crashing because you are calling hideTimeline and removing the SWF when the SWF is waiting for a response. Try starting a timer in hideTimeline that will topper.removeChild(document.getElementById('timeLineer'));
 after like 50 miliseconds.

Comment: That seems to have done it! Submit it as an answer and I'll accecpt it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plug in might be crashing because you are calling hideTimeline and removing the SWF when the SWF is waiting for a response.
Try starting a timer in hideTimeline that will removeChild after like 50

```
miliseconds.topper.removeChild(document.getElementById('timeLineer'));
```